# Running the kinesis producer and consumer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-kinesis

I was able to successfully follow the AWS kinesis tutorial [here](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-client-nodejs):

However, in this tutorial we are running the producer and consumer on local machine.

So I am guessing in production, we have to create two EC2 instances

1. for a producer
2. for consumer

which means we are back to managing the server infrastructure. Am i understanding this right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, I would recommend deploying producer and consumer apps to two instances, so that they are de-coupled, and well thats the point of service-oriented architecture :) 
You definitely do not want to stop the `producer-app` when you have to deploy changes in `consumer-app` and vice versa + many more.

I did not quite understand when you say `back to managing the server infrastructure?`, which you have to otherwise how you gonna deploy the applications.